# Will the PDF rendered VF page can have buttons where user can click

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered

I have designed a solution to generate a document for each record with the values from the record by having button that will generate a PDF form of the record with selected fields and there values.

I have a question that is it possible to add button to the PDF rendered VF page where user can click it.

Comment: I am not sure about button, but I think it is possible for links  -- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000950ZIAQ. Just ensure to put full URL

Comment: What should the button do? Can't use a link styled as button instead as @kurunve suggested?

Comment: @mascot the button functionality is to send mail to the customer

Comment: Your question is _Can rendered VF page have buttons_, now you are saying that you want to send email. Can you please explain your requirement in detail?

Comment: @SamuelRobert you can make that link of course, but to make it working, you need to have authorized user into appropriate salesforce org. I can not even imagine any single scenario when I want to send an email from PDF

Comment: then you would have to create the link as @kuruvne describe in his answer which will call custom Visualforce page, which has the controller with the method to send the email on the page load.

Comment: @SarojBera,@mascot , Let me tell the complete ideology of mine. I create a button in the custom object detail page and the button reference to a VF page that renders as PDF taking the values from the custom object. Now I want to create a Button in the PDF saying send email on clicking the button I want to send a email to the customer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible
There is an example below, that shows couple of links (as link, as buttons and as custom URL field as link type)

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" 
               standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" 
               sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false"  >
    <body>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="https://google.com">Some custom link</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="https://google.com" 
               style="font: bold 11px Arial;text-decoration: none; 
                      background-color: #EEEEEE;color: #333333;padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
                      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid #333333;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; 
                      border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
                 Some link like a button
            </a>
        </div>
        <apex:detail subject="{!Account.Id}" relatedList="false" inlineEdit="false" showChatter="false"  />
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

If render as pdf, can result as pdf shown below:
[image]

All the links are clickable (at least in google chrome preview) and lead to appropriate page.